# Unable to save attachments from Exchange Server 2010 using EWS Managed API

Tags: c#, exchange-server

I am getting following error while trying to read attachments from Exchange Server 2010 using EWS Managed API.

The request failed. Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Please find my code below. Getting error at fileAttachment.Load

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);

        try
        {
            service.Url = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EWS"]);

            service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("XXXX", "XXX", "XXX");

            FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new ItemView(100));

            EmailMessage message;

            foreach (Item item in findResults.Items)
            {
                message = EmailMessage.Bind(service, item.Id, new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, ItemSchema.Attachments));

                message.Load();

                if (message.HasAttachments)
                {
                    foreach (Attachment attachment in message.Attachments)
                    {
                        if (attachment is FileAttachment)
                        {
                            FileAttachment fileAttachment = attachment as FileAttachment;

                            fileAttachment.Load(@"C:\Mohan\Mail\" + fileAttachment.Name);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }           
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: The remote host is closing the connection so this most likely network related eg how large is the attachment your trying to download ? how good is the network connection ? is it being proxied etc